# ASP.Net - Possible to edit multi rows in grid, then save all? PLUS...partial postback of single row with new value retrieval from dataset

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I need to implement a grid in asp.net that behaves almost exactly like MS Excel.
- can navigate around with arrow keys
- you can edit the cell that currently has focus by simply typing
- supports checkboxes, dropdownlists, etc

One crucial requirement is....I need to be able to *somehow*, after update of any cell within a row, pass that updated value back to the server, as there is a calculation process that happens using that updated value that can update  other cells in the row, and I need to essentially rebind all the cells in the current row with the updated values resulting from the calculation.  AND...when I do this, I want to retain focus on the cell that had it after the update of the former cell.  Without grid scrolling, etc, etc.

If you're wondering what I'm talking about, just imagine Microsoft Excel, but I need to perform the formula calculations on the server and refresh all cells in the current row with the results....and, not lose focus of my current cell.

I am more than happy to pay $1000 or whatever it is for one of the full blown commercial ASP.Net grid controls, but from the ones I have tried so far, they seem to not be capable of this, at least I don't know how.
Aspose Grid - would have worked great, except it is totally full of bugs
Telerik RadGrid - a colleague familiar with that grid is trying to figure it out with no luck
Farpoint Grid - looks promising but haven't tried it out yet

If anyone has any advice on how to specifically accomplish this, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Telerik controls are a pain in the arse unfortunately, they look pretty sexy, but don't believe a word of the 'codeless' mantra they put out. That being said the multiline edit is available on the RadGrid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the [extjs](http://extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/grid/edit-grid.html) sample?
It has a commercial licence, but you can try it for free.

Comment: I have briefly looked at extjs in the past, and have read that it is a bit of work getting it to work with asp.net (someone has even started a wrapper).....are you familiar enough with it to give and educated guess on how hard it would be to accomplish my task?

Comment: extjs has come a long way since this was first answered, so as of now I would say it would be the superior solution.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find an example about Excel-like RadGrid by Telerik - if you are interested in it, you can see it [here](http://www.telerik.com/community/code-library/aspnet-ajax/grid/excel-like-radgrid.aspx). And good luck with your implementation.

Answer (score -1):

Did you look into using jQuery for this? Look into jQuery templates and ajax.